# Error on amazon SES: SendEmail operation: Illegal addres

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to send email through [AWS SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/setting-up-email.html), but I'm receiving this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the SendEmail operation: Illegal address
```

I already verified the email I'm sending to and from.
This is my code:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
    'ses',
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY
)


response = client.send_email(
    Destination={
        'ToAddresses': [
            'xxx@xxx.com',
        ],
    },
    Message={
        'Body': {
            'Html': {
                'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                'Data': 'This message body contains HTML formatting. It can, for example, contain links like this one: <a class="ulink" href="http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide" target="_blank">Amazon SES Developer Guide</a>.',
            },
            'Text': {
                'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                'Data': 'This is the message body in text format.',
            },
        },
        'Subject': {
            'Charset': 'UTF-8',
            'Data': 'Test email',
        },
    },
    ReplyToAddresses=[
    ],
    ReturnPath='',
    ReturnPathArn='',
    Source='xxx@xxx.com',
    SourceArn='',
)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Though the email address may be "valid" (working), it may not be in a format acceptable to SES.  Only 7 bit ASCII can be used without encoding.  Are there unicode characters at code points higher than 127 in the address (like `é` or `ñ`, for example)?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try to remove the following:

```
    ReplyToAddresses=[],
    ReturnPath='',
    ReturnPathArn='',
    SourceArn='',
```

Apparently they can't be empty!

Comment: Saved me a ton of time, AWS got to fix their documentation, its very misleading http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendEmail-property

Comment: Yea, incredibly useful answer.  If only the docs weren't utterly wrong.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, but using the Java SDK! (`com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:1.11.271`).

Comment: I'm embarrassed how long I spent on this error, bad documentation and bad error message! Thanksfor your help!

Comment: This also resolves the problem for `InvalidParameterValue: Invalid email address`

Answer (score 2):

Although it isn't applicable to this question, in my case, I was trying to send emails to multiple addresses at the same time.

Having a single email address here helped.

```
'ToAddresses': [
            'xxx@xxx.com',
        ],
```